# Inject router into controller method in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5

Does anyone know why can't one use controller method injection in Laravel 5 to make the $router singleton available inside a controllers method, like in the code below?

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;

class WelcomeController extends Controller {
    // ...
    public function test($name = 'default var value', Router $router)
    {
        // stuff like taking the {name} part of /say-hello-to/{name?}
        // ...using $router->input('name') for example
        // ...assuming a route like: Route::get('say-hello-to/{name?}', 'WelcomeController@test') 
    }
}
```

An alternative way to get the same thing (idiomatic access to an url part inside a controller method) is useful, but I've already thought of a way to do this and **I'm mainly interested in why this doesn't just work, as what I'm trying to get is a deeper understanding of how Laravel works and what advanced patterns can one emply when working with it**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I first thought about deleting this after I figured out the answer myself in ~5min, but then again, maybe it's better to write this for others to be able to google:

When combining optional URL arguments (like `'test/{name?}'`) with controller method injection, **always put the injected parameters before the ones with default values in the method declaration**, otherwise you will end up staring at some pretty confusing errors when accessing the URL variant without the optional parameter.

So, in the example above, it should have been:

`public function test(Router $router, $name = 'default var value')`

...instead of:

`public function test($name = 'default var value', Router $router)`

And, btw, if someone more experienced with Laravel than me comes across this, please comment if you think this is a Laravel 5 bug that should be reported to the developers, or if you think this is the intended behavior for such situations.

Comment: Are you sure about this? This doesn't make sense. It should be like the first shape.

Comment: This in the intended behavior. Without a specific order in the params, it would be harder for the framework to guess what is something that should be injected and what is just a route param. It's not impossible to achieve that, but it seems the extra logic doesn't worth it. **Disclaimer**: I'm not part of Laravel dev team so this based only on my experience.